# Is there any nontrivial measure on $L^p$ or Sobolev spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

One may find a counting measure or trivial probability measure on $L^p$. However, is there any meaningful measure constructed on $L^p$, so that one may try to find a size of subsets of $L^p$? The same question goes for the $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ spaces as well.

My attempt: $L^p$ (constructed on any measure space) is a topological vector space so we can construct Borel $\sigma$-algebra. We can think of next measure for $r$-balls: $$\mu_0(B_r(f))=r \quad(\text{or }r^2,r^3,e^r,\text{etc})$$ where $$B_r(f)=\{g\in L^p:\|f-g\|_{L^p}<r\}.$$ Then $\mu_0$ can be extended to a pre-measure on the ring $$\mathcal{B}:=\bigg\{\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{r_i}(f_i):r_i\geq 0,f_i\in L^p,\text{$B_{r_i}(f_i)$ are pairwise disjoint},\,\text{$I$ any index set}\bigg\}.$$ So we can use Carathéodory's extension theorem to find a measure $\mu$ on Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $L^p$. Is there any study on such $\mu$? Here I just needed that $L^p$ is a topological vector space. So it seems quite a general result, thus I suspect there is already a name for it, but I could not find any.

Comment: Your proposed measure suggests that we should think of $L^p$ as somehow 1-dimensional, which I'm not sure is intuitively correct.  Probably you want $I$ countable?

Comment: @LSpice I don't understand how this measure suggests that (somehow) $L^p$ is 1-dimensional? Can you elaborate a little? :)

Comment: [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) is one way of stating that "being $n$-dimensional" is related to $\mu(B_r) \sim r^n$.  Your measure is the case $n = 1$.  (Also, I think that your pre-measure does not measure all of $L^p$.)

Comment: I see your point. Indeed, but since $L^p$ is infinite-dimensional, what would be 'intuitively correct' to measure $r$-ball? Maybe $e^r$? And for the pre-measure, surely it does not measure all sets in $L^p$, but that's why we are using the extension theorem. Sorry if this was not what you were trying to say.

Comment: I think the fact that there's no intuitively correct reason suggests that either we shouldn't be trying to measure infinite-dimensional spaces, or that we need to use some extra structure other than the bare normed structure. // I meant to say not that we couldn't measure every subset of $L^p$ but that the pre-measure didn't measure $L^p$ itself, but I see, on checking my definitions, that that doesn't seem to be part of the definition, so it's of no consequence.  (One still needs some sort of requirement to guarantee that $L^p$ can be covered by countably many balls, but that's often true.)

Comment: Taking $B_\infty(0)=L^p$, it would be $\mu_0(L^p)=+\infty$. But yes, this is of no importance, I guess.

Comment: I think the title of your question is misleading, it depends on "what is a non trivial measure". Is any image measure on $L^p$ trivial? I think a better title is "Is there any Borel measure in $L^p$ such that each ball with same radius has the same finite measure?" Of course this can be asked for any infinite dimensional Banach space. If I must bet I would say no.Compare the measure of a ball with radius $1$ and $2$.

Comment: The measure you're trying to construct would be translation invariant, and it's a famous and not-too-difficult fact that there can be no nontrivial translation invariant Borel measure on an infinite-dimensional Banach space.  This is often summarized as ["there is no infinite-dimensional Lebesgue measure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure).  There are lots of interesting measures without this property; for instance there is a deep theory of Gaussian probability measures on Banach spaces.  But no one of them is truly "canonical".

Comment: For example, a one-dimensional Brownian motion run until time 1 produces a random continuous path, which in particular is in $L^p([0,1])$ for any $p$.  So this induces a (Gaussian) probability measure on $L^p$; the pushforward of the Wiener measure on $C([0,1])$ under the inclusion map $C([0,1]) \hookrightarrow L^p([0,1])$

Comment: @NateEldredge Wow. So the measure I constructed would be the trivial measure, which is a contradiction. So there is something I am doing wrong. Thank you for the reference, this was very close to what I was looking for. And for other examples, thank you as well, they are very helpful.

Comment: @JingeonAn: What's shown in the proof is that, for instance, each ball of radius 1 contains infinitely many disjoint balls of radius 1/4.  So your "premeasure" isn't a premeasure because it isn't monotone.  Anyway your collection $\mathcal{B}$ isn't a ring because it isn't closed under relative complement (take one ball and remove a smaller ball from its inside, the resulting set is not a disjoint union of balls, e.g. by connectedness).

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. For pre-measure that I know of, does not have to be monotone (in sense of $A\subset B$ implies $\mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$), but indeed $\mathcal{B}$ is not a ring. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JingeonAn: Well, if $\mathcal{B}$ were a ring, then monotonicity of $\mu$ would follow from finite additivity.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah. It is quite surprising that there is no Lebesgue-measure-like measure on infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. Yet, in the reference you gave me (Wikipedia), the Banach space has to be separable, which is not the case of $L^\infty$. I guess this does not change the conclusion?

Comment: I actually don't know for sure.  The proof doesn't quite go through in that case, though it does show that the measure would have to have a variety of unpleasant properties and could not be very geometrically meaningful.  Questions about non-separable Banach spaces sometimes involve deep set theory and contain strange pathologies.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think your comment became enough of an answer, so why don't you post it as an answer (if you do not think my question is not suitable here)?